# Getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDPattern.toRGB

Tags: html, pdf, dom, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox-2.0.9 in my java application to convert a PDF file to html. But I am getting

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDPattern.toRGB(PDPattern.java:95)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PathDrawer.pdfColorToColor(PathDrawer.java:133)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PathDrawer.clearPathGraphics(PathDrawer.java:79)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PathDrawer.drawPath(PathDrawer.java:59)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PDFDomTree.createPathImage(PDFDomTree.java:403)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PDFDomTree.renderPath(PDFDomTree.java:251)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PDFBoxTree.processOperator(PDFBoxTree.java:499)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:477)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.showForm(PDFStreamEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.DrawObject.process(DrawObject.java:65)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:848)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PDFBoxTree.processOperator(PDFBoxTree.java:542)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:477)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:150)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.processPage(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:391)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PDFBoxTree.processPage(PDFBoxTree.java:208)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:319)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:266)
    at org.fit.pdfdom.PDFDomTree.createDOM(PDFDomTree.java:218)
    at com.demo.pdf.converter.PdfProcessor.convertToHtml(PdfProcessor.java:87)
```

The pdf I am trying to convert can be accessed from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=13v3GJCvzt4dLrm8qXtai7CVfpCfU2rv-).

Comment: Please modify the permissions so that everybody can have access. I suspect this is a bug in PDF2Dom, a pattern in a PDF can't be converted to a RGB color. (Think about it - e.g. a dots pattern isn't one RGB color, it is a vector graphics instruction).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have modified permission for pdf.

Comment: Thanks, the file renders without problem. Of course this PDF2Dom application is something different. Try a few of the files in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1094, all have patterns. I'd expect that they will all produce this exception. If it does, then please open an issue here: https://github.com/radkovo/Pdf2Dom/issues . However the project doesn't look very active. I submitted a one line PR in August and nothing happened. The last commit is from May.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have checked the code from org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDPattern class, toRGB method is directly throwing UnsupportedOperationException without any other processing.  Do you have any idea why it's done so?

Comment: Because it shouldn't be called for patterns for the reason I mentioned in my first comment. PDFBox follows the design of the PDF specification and in the PDF specification, a pattern is used as a "color" for fill / stroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is resolved in PDF2Dom v1.9. I tried the pdf you provided with this version and it's getting converted appropriately.
 No exceptions thrown.
Please confirm by updating PDF2Dom to v1.9
You can find latest dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.cssbox/pdf2dom/1.9) .